# awk calculate average or zero

Tags: bash, awk

I am calculating the average for a bunch of numbers in a bunch of text files like this:

```
grep '^num' file.$i | awk '{ sum += $2 } END { print sum / NR }'
```

But some times the file doesn't contain the pattern, in which cas I want the script to return zero. Any ideas of this slightly modified one-liner?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You're adding to your load (average) by spawning an extra process to do everything the first can do.  Using 'grep' and 'awk' together is a red-flag.  You would be better to write:

```
awk '/^num/ {n++;sum+=$2} END {print n?sum/n:0}' file
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
... END { print NR ? sum/NR : 0 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use awk's ternary operator, i.e. `m ? m : n` which means, if m has a value '?', use it, else ':' use this other value. Both n and m can be strings, numbers, or expressions that produce a value.

```
grep '^num' file.$i | awk '{ sum += $2 } END { print sum ? sum / NR : 0.0 }'
```

Comment: Other answers already point out the useless `grep`, but maybe you want to fix that still.