# Use awk to find average of a column

Tags: bash, awk

I'm attempting to find the average of the second column of data using `awk` for a class. This is my current code, with the framework my instructor provided:

```
#!/bin/awk

### This script currently prints the total number of rows processed.
### You must edit this script to print the average of the 2nd column
### instead of the number of rows.

# This block of code is executed for each line in the file
{
x=sum
read name
        awk 'BEGIN{sum+=$2}'
        # The script should NOT print out a value for each line
}
# The END block is processed after the last line is read
END {
        # NR is a variable equal to the number of rows in the file
        print "Average: " sum/ NR
        # Change this to print the Average instead of just the number of rows
}
```

and I'm getting an error that says:

```
awk: avg.awk:11:        awk 'BEGIN{sum+=$2}' $name
awk: avg.awk:11:            ^ invalid char ''' in expression
```

I think I'm close but I really have no idea where to go from here. The code shouldn't be incredibly complex as everything we've seen in class has been fairly basic. Please let me know.

Comment: I'm not much on awk, but does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8434000/awk-calculate-average-or-zero?rq=1

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your specific error is with line 11:

```
awk 'BEGIN{sum+=$2}'
```

This is a line where `awk` is invoked, and its `BEGIN` block is specified - but you are already within a awk script, so you do not need to specify `awk`. Also you want to run `sum+=$2` on each line of input, so you do not want it within a `BEGIN` block. Hence the line should simply read:

```
sum+=$2
```

You also do not need the lines:

```
x=sum
read name
```

the first just creates a synonym to `sum` named `x` and I'm not sure what the second does, but neither are needed.

This would make your awk script:

```
#!/bin/awk

### This script currently prints the total number of rows processed.
### You must edit this script to print the average of the 2nd column
### instead of the number of rows.

# This block of code is executed for each line in the file
{
    sum+=$2
    # The script should NOT print out a value for each line
}
# The END block is processed after the last line is read
END {
    # NR is a variable equal to the number of rows in the file
    print "Average: " sum/ NR
    # Change this to print the Average instead of just the number of rows
}
```

Jonathan Leffler's answer gives the awk one liner which represents the same fixed code, with the addition of checking that there are at least 1 lines of input (this stops any divide by zero error). If

Comment: That did the trick, thanks so much! I didn't realize because it was in an awk script that there was no need for the awk command, rookie mistake. Thanks again

Answer (score 167):

```
awk '{ sum += $2; n++ } END { if (n > 0) print sum / n; }'
```

Add the numbers in `$2` (second column) in `sum` (variables are auto-initialized to zero by `awk`) and increment the number of rows (which could also be handled via built-in variable NR).  At the end, if there was at least one value read, print the average.

```
awk '{ sum += $2 } END { if (NR > 0) print sum / NR }'
```

If you want to use the shebang notation, you could write:

```
#!/bin/awk

{ sum += $2 }
END { if (NR > 0) print sum / NR }
```

You can also control the format of the average with `printf()` and a suitable format (`"%13.6e\n"`, for example).

You can also generalize the code to average the Nth column (with `N=2` in this sample) using:

```
awk -v N=2 '{ sum += $N } END { if (NR > 0) print sum / NR }'
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
ls -l  | awk -F : '{sum+=$5} END {print "AVG=",sum/NR}'
```

NR is an AWK builtin variable to count the no. of records

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you add a new answer to a question that is some months old and that includes an accepted answer, then your new answer needs to provide some distinctive new information.  It isn't clear that this does the job.  It isn't obvious why you're feeding `ls -l` into `awk`; nor is it clear why you're using `:` as the field separator. The question states it needs to sum column 2, so it is not obvious why you sum column 5.

Comment: how to print the file name at the same time?

Answer (score 3):

```
awk 's+=$2{print s/NR}' table | tail -1
```

I am using `tail -1` to print the last line which should have the average number...

Comment: A very weird way of doing things.  It works, but I can't think of a good reason for using this technique.