# How to use awk to calculate average of inputs?

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have a file that contains many values :

```html
10 ; 20 ; 30 ; 40 ;
20 ; 11 ; 15 ; 70 ;
60 ; 50 ; 80 ; 84 ;
```

How to calculate the average of value in COLUMNS using awk :

the Output desired :

```html
30;27;41.6;64.66;
```

Any solutions welcome, including bash ones.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19149731/3093378

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In awk, you can just translate exactly what you're asking for:

```
 awk -F\; 'BEGIN{
     ORS=";"
 }
 {
     for (i=1;i<=NF;++i) {
         sum[i] += $i
     }
 }
 END {
     for (i=1;i<=NF;++i) {
         print sum[i]/NR
     }
     print "\n"
 }'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can build an array to store the sums of columns, and in `END` block to calculate the average:

```
awk -F';' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)a[i]+=$i}
     END{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)printf "%.2f%s",a[i]/NR,i==NF?RS:FS}' file
```

outputs:

```
30.00;27.00;41.67;64.67
```

Comment: it works but it gaves me : 30.00;27.00;41.67;64.67;0.00

Comment: @Alexander you changed input! My codes are for your original input. If you change the delimiter, you can even say my codes don't work at all. Add empty string check in the codes then.