# Adding / averaging several variables in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, variables, scripting

I have this problem that I've been wrestling with for the better part of the night. I need to get this script to add the variables and then average them out, and also display the student name, total points and average after the calculations.

Here's what I have:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "================"
echo "Grade Calculator"
echo "================"

read -p "Enter first name: " $FirstName
read -p "Enter last name: " $LastName

read -p "Enter test score 1: " $ScoreOne
read -p "Enter test score 2: " $ScoreTwo
read -p "Enter test score 3: " $ScoreThree
read -p "Enter test score 4: " $ScoreFour
read -p "Enter lab score: " $Lab
Total=expr `$ScoreOne + $ScoreTwo + $ScoreThree + $ScoreFour + $Lab`

echo "Grade results. . ."
echo "Student name: $FirstName $LastName"
echo "Total points: $Total"
```

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: agree with below, but you can also do `Total=\`expr ....\`` . Good luck.

Comment: @shelter, sure sir, added `expr` way also in code now too.

Comment: Use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19149731/use-awk-to-find-average-of-a-column and pipe the scores on standard input. Probably use Awk to print the results nicely, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Editing your script itself, could you please try following and let me know if that helps.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "================"
echo "Grade Calculator"
echo "================"

read -p "Enter first name: " FirstName
read -p "Enter last name: " LastName

read -p "Enter test score 1: " ScoreOne
read -p "Enter test score 2: " ScoreTwo
read -p "Enter test score 3: " ScoreThree
read -p "Enter test score 4: " ScoreFour
read -p "Enter lab score: " Lab
Total=$((ScoreOn + ScoreTwo + ScoreThree + ScoreFour + Lab))

echo "Grade results. . ."
echo "Student name: $FirstName $LastName"
echo "Total points: $Total"
```

***EDIT:*** If you want to use `expr` you could change above code's `total` variable line with following then:

```
Total=$(expr "$ScoreOne" + "$ScoreTwo" + "$ScoreThree" + "$ScoreFour")
```

Comment: You really *don't* want to use `expr` if you have a modern shell.

Comment: @tripleee, sure since OP was using `expr` so I have added that solution too in now, thanks for your views sir.

Answer (score 0):

Your disappearing variable values can be explained by:

```
read -p "Enter first name: " $FirstName
read -p "Enter last name: " $LastName
```

(**note:** the improper `'$'` before the variable name. You do not include the `'$'` when assigning values)

While you can take input into fixed variable names, by doing so, you limit yourself to a script with limited functionality that can take no more (or no less) that the number of values that you specify variable names for. Another way to approach the same problem is simply to read the values within a loop that will terminate when the user presses <kbd>Enter</kbd> on a blank line (without entering a score).

Since your question is tagged bash, you can simply test whether the input is a integer grade and then add the value to an array. When input is complete, you can then compute any statistic regarding the grades you like. (you can sum the values at the time of input or after input is complete)

Bash does not provide any type of floating point number handling, so for your average, you enlist the help of `bc` (or `calc`) that can compute the floating point value for your.

Putting the pieces together, you can do something like the following. (there are many way you can approach this)

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a grades
declare -i total=0

echo "================"
echo "Grade Calculator"
echo "================"

read -p "Enter first name: " FirstName
read -p "Enter last name: " LastName

score=" "
## loop collecting grades until user presses return on empty line
printf "(Press return on empty line to end input)\n-----------------\n"
while [ -n "$score" ]; do
    read -p "Enter test score: " score
    ## validate integer and add to array
    [ "$score" -eq "$score" >/dev/null 2>&1 ] && grades+=( $score )
done

echo "Grade results. . ."
echo "Student name: $FirstName $LastName"
printf "\ngrades:\n"
for i in "${grades[@]}"; do
    printf "  %3d\n" "$i"
    total=$((total + i))
done
printf -- " -----\n  %3d  total\n\n" "$total"

## compute average with bc
printf "Average: %s\n" $(printf "scale=2; %d / %d\n" $total ${#grades[@]} | bc)
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ bash tmp/grades.sh
================
Grade Calculator
================
Enter first name: John
Enter last name: Doe
(Press return on empty line to end input)
-----------------
Enter test score: 88
Enter test score: 94
Enter test score: 92
Enter test score: 80
Enter test score: 87
Enter test score:
Grade results. . .
Student name: John Doe

grades:
   88
   94
   92
   80
   87
 -----
  441  total

Average: 88.20
```

By checking that the users entered an integer as input, your input is not affected if a mistake is made, e.g.

```
Enter test score: 88
Enter test score: uugh, messed up
Enter test score: 92
```

(the non-integer input is simply ignored)

Comment: Thank you both!  I knew it was a simple issue of me not knowing what the hell I'm doing...but I'm learning!

Comment: @Hebruiser You'll get there. Bash is a fantastic shell. There is very little you cannot do in it. Bookmarks to add to help you learn: [**Bash Guide**](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide) and [**Bash FAQ**](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ) and [**Bash Pitfalls**](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls)