# Calculate Average from a file and show records of students whose average is more than 90

Tags: awk, command-line-interface, average

I have a file named `input.txt` which contains students data in  `StudentName # ClassName #SchoolName # Subject1Marks # Subject2Marks` format.

```
Shriii#First#ADCET#95#90
Chaitraliii#Second#ADCET#80#75
Shubhangi#First#ADCET#75#70
Tushar#Second#RIT#80#79
Prathamesh#First#RIT#88#63
```

The output should contains record of students whose average is more than 90. I have to show the average in new column.

The expected output is `Shriii|First|ADCET|95|90|92.5` I tried various ways but was not able to generate expected output. I tried [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19149731/use-awk-to-find-average-of-a-column/19149931) [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8434000/awk-calculate-average-or-zero?rq=1)

Comment: What did you learn from those questions? Did you understand the code you tried? What questions do you have about it (aside from "Can someone do this for me?")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk -F# -v OFS='|' '{$(NF+1)=($(NF-1)+$NF)/2}1' file

Shriii|First|ADCET|95|90|92.5
Chaitraliii|Second|ADCET|80|75|77.5
Shubhangi|First|ADCET|75|70|72.5
Tushar|Second|RIT|80|79|79.5
Prathamesh|First|RIT|88|63|75.5
Sukrut|Second|KIT|91|90|90.5
```

or pipe to `column` to get pretty output

```
... | column -ts'|'

Shriii       First   ADCET  95  90  92.5
Chaitraliii  Second  ADCET  80  75  77.5
Shubhangi    First   ADCET  75  70  72.5
Tushar       Second  RIT    80  79  79.5
Prathamesh   First   RIT    88  63  75.5
Sukrut       Second  KIT    91  90  90.5
```